# I tried to run a test plan in Jmeter but no results are displayed when I try to see the result as "view results as tree"

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing, stress-testing

Whenever I run the test, the response I got on the error log is shown in the screenshot.  Anyone who has an idea about this? please share it. It would be helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. There are no any errors in your screenshot, only information messages regarding each of 10 threads start/stop event
2. You need to have at least one [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers), currently your test plan doesn't contain any samplers so threads don't have any work to do. Most probably you need [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler. If you're uncertain about HTTP Request sampler configuration - you can record your test scenario using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)

   HTTP Request Defaults doesn't create any load, it provides **default** values for all HTTP Request samplers in its scope (so you could perform configuration at one place and won't need to re-visit each and every sampler)

Comment: Please can you tell me in a detailed solution for this exactly what I have to do?

Comment: First of all add a [HTTP Request sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request), it might be sufficient given you properly configured host, port, path, etc. in the [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults). HTTP Request Defaults per se doesn't send any requests, it only configures HTTP Requests samplers by providing default values to them